# How to get Term ID by its custom field?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, database

I'd like to get Term ID by its custom field. I would like to do this using [EntityFieldQuery()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7).

Here's what I have so far:

```
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
    ->propertyCondition('vid', '1')
    //I need help with this line:
    ->fieldCondition('field_foo', $fieldValue)
    ->range(0,1)
    ->execute();
```

**Update** - I'm providing screenshots to make it more sense.

Here's a view of the custom field

[image]

I'm basically trying to get "myTermName" Name field, by "myValue" Foo field.

[image]

Comment: did it not worked?

Comment: Nope. It's not returning anything. The $fieldValue is supposed to be an actual string of the field_foo, not the ID. Maybe that's why?

Comment: `->fieldCondition('field_yourfield', 'value', $yourvalue, '=')`

Comment: `->fieldCondition('field_number', 'value', '1', '=');`

Comment: First one doesn't work. Second gives an unexpected site error.

Comment: those are examples/pattern, not solutions.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is undefined value in `fieldCondition`. there are some examples listed below. try one of these format.

```
->fieldCondition('field_foo', 'tid', array('12','13'), 'IN')
->fieldCondition('field_foo', 'value', 'spotlight', '=')
->fieldCondition('field_foo', 'fid', 'NULL', '!=')
->fieldCondition('field_foo', 'tid', $value)
->fieldCondition('field_foo', 'value', $year. '%', 'like')
->fieldCondition('field_foo', 'value', NULL);
```

Comment: `->fieldCondition('field_foo', 'value', $value, '=')` would seem the most sense, but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to see the mysql query it's creating?

Comment: `->fieldCondition('field_foo', 'value', $value, '=')` does work! I had to make corrections in the other area of the query.